# I cant use my left control key and Function key while the right one work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I cant use my left control key and fn key.So is there anyway can i fix it?Since I am new to Ubuntu I dont know much about this and i got stuck and I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64 bit version.And the Gnome version is 3.36.3 and the windowing system is X11.Please if there is anyway I can try please describe clearly cuz I dont know how things work here.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `settings->Devices->keyboard` and have a look at the desired keys if they're set up accordingly.

Comment: I've tried but there is no devices setting in my settings.